# How to apply HTML5 fullscreen API to div background image

Tags: css, html, background, fullscreen

Want to apply HTML 5 fullscreen APi to background image of div

```
<div class="bgimg" style="background-image:url('img/home-1.jpg')" />
   <img src="img/fullscreen.png" id="fullscreen-btn">
</div>
```

I want onclick `fullscreen-btn` background image of div `bgimg` ie `home-1.jpg` should open in fullscreen. I tried below code but not workin Kindlt suggest

```
<scritpt>
$(function() {
    var bg = $('.bgimg');
    $('#fullscreen-btn').click(function () {   
      goFullScreen(bg.attr('style', 'background-image:url()')); 
    });
});

function goFullScreen( element )
{
    if ( element === undefined )
    {
        // If no element defined, use entire document
        element = document.documentElement;
    }

    if ( element.requestFullScreen )
    {
        // Spec, supported by Opera 12.1+
        element.requestFullScreen();
    }
    else if ( element.mozRequestFullScreen )
    {
        // Supported by Firefox 10+
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if ( element.webkitRequestFullScreen )
    {
        // Supported by Chrome 15+ & Safari 5.1+
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    // Still no IE support, sorry folks :( 
}
```

Comment: please define "not workin"

Comment: Its just remove background Image. If I use goFullScreen(document.getElementById("id")); then it show fullscreen content in element with that id. Even if id is assign to div.bgimg and try goFullScreen it show fullscreen div along with all content in it. I want to show only background image in fullscreen.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this API but I would guess you need to include the image path in this line: `goFullScreen(bg.attr('style', 'background-image:url()'));` Similar to how you have it in your html.

Comment: Tried it. But not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me. You just needed to add the image path in your javascript with quotes around it.

```
$(function() {
    var bg = $('.bgimg');
    $('#fullscreen-btn').click(function () {   
      goFullScreen(bg.attr('style', "background-image:url('img/home-1.jpg')")); 
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jth2013/9d9d7jf3/)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but will admit am not 100% sure, that the fullscreen API can only full screen an HTML *element*. So that is why it will fullscreen `div.bgimg` but will not fullscreen the background image of the element. `<img>` is an HTML element, however, so I would think that would work. Is there any reason you would not want to use that instead of setting the background image of your divs?

If so, you could try to wire up some JS that connects visible divs with the background images (Like what you have now) to invisible images and load those to your fullscreen script instead.

Comment: it is what I concluded so far is If anyhow I can manage to create `DOM` objects then fullscreen works example `document.getElementById("id")` How I can create `DOM` object of bg image? (As you suggested using invisible element is last option if nothing is works out.)

Comment: Is there any reason not to just insert the image as part of the DOM directly?

`<div class="bgimg" />
<img src="img/home-1.jpg" id="fullscreen-btn">
</div>`

Comment: I am trying to create fullscreen background image slider. Main div is 'bgimg' which contain lot more element like caption, text and thumbnail.

Comment: So you want in 'normal mode' 1) caption, 2) other text, 3) thumbnail, 4) background image. In full screen mode, you want just the background image? Trying to make sure I understand the goal before I make more suggestions.

Comment: Just background Image of `div.bgimg`

Comment: Was my description of 'normal mode' correct?

If not, you are going to need to either post more code or more explaination of your project. I can't be helpful without more context.

Comment: Okay, so here is what I would do, if you really don't want to load in an <img> element where I originally suggested (still think that is the best idea). Put the full img resource into your 'thumbnail' div (which I'm assuming would be an <img> element) and target that with your fullscreen script. So just don't down sample for a thumbnail. Use the exact same resource. It's essentially the same solution as the invisible divs, you just didn't mention a thumbnail before. You can call `goFullScreen(document.getElementById("id-thumbnail"))`. It's not super elegant, but it should work.

Comment: If I want to choose between invisible img element vs thumbnail with full img resource then abiviously I will prefer former. Totally agree on this with you. Still Want to find a way to load fullscreen image from css.background-image

Comment: Yeah, sorry man. I have not seen it done from CSS. You can look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode and here: http://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/ but they only talk about elements http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element